# When the browser fails to verify the ssl certificate, what will the browser do next?

Tags: ssl, browser, https

For example, after the browser prompts the risk, should it continue to establish the https connection with the untrusted certificate or fall back to the http connection or what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL says `https://`, then the browser will not fallback to `http://`. It will instead bring a warning about broken validation. If the reported issue is bypassable (not when HSTS is configured for the domain) and the user explicitly asked to bypass it, then it will store the users decision to ignore the problem in the future when this specific certificate is used for this specific domain. Then it will retry the `https://` and if the certificate is the same as previously accepted as valid, will continue to get the URL.

Comment: Depending on configuration, and the kind of TLS problem encountered, the browser might not even let the users bypass the warning and the error is fatal. For example for all domains in the HSTS preloading list.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Thanks. I've added this detail to the answer.